# T-SQL: SELECT posts where trend is downwards on two time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want to avoid doing sub-select on a table to compare two periods and if the trend is downwards.

This select gets the percentage on one period

```
SELECT user, (SUM(value1)/SUM(value2)) AS percentage1
FROM table
WHERE (date BETWEEN @start1 AND @end1)
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY 2
```

This query gets the result I am after but is not very efficient because there are over 100 million rows.

```
SELECT t1.user, (SUM(t1.value1)/SUM(t1.value2)) AS percentage1,
(SELECT (SUM(t2.value1)/SUM(t2.value2)) AS percentage2
FROM table AS t2
WHERE t2.userID = t1.userID
AND (t2.date BETWEEN @start2 AND @end2)
)
FROM table AS t1
WHERE (t1.date BETWEEN @start1 AND @end1)
AND (SUM(t1.value1)/SUM(t1.value2)) < (SELECT (SUM(t2.value1)/SUM(t2.value2))
FROM table AS t2
WHERE t2.userID = t1.userID
AND (t2.date BETWEEN @start2 AND @end2)
)
GROUP BY t1.user
```

Is there a better way of doing this? One solution could be to just have a date period then group on the month(date), year(date) and compare with the previous month instead of having two exact dates. But grouping on month and year just gives several rows for each user and that I want to avoid.

Just want a clean result like this:

```
Adam, 43%, 47%
Lisa, 22%, 25%
John, 18%, 34%
```

Excluding rows like this because the trend is a lower percentage

```
Bill, 24%, 18%
Nina, 84%, 56%
```

SQL-Server 2016 Enterprise is the DB.

Comment: sample data would be awesome her,  and defining what all of your variables are

Comment: Addeladde goto http://sqlfiddle.com and setup a Schema for us to play with.  You are not providing a whole lot of information or data-set to evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT G1.user, G1.percentage1, G2.percentage2 
FROM 
    ( SELECT t1.user, t1.userID
        (SUM(t1.value1)/SUM(t1.value2)) AS percentage1,
      FROM table AS t1
      WHERE 
        (t1.date BETWEEN @start1 AND @end1)
      GROUP BY t1.user, t1.userID
    ) AS G1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT t2.userID, (SUM(t2.value1)/SUM(t2.value2)) AS percentage2
        FROM table AS t2
        WHERE 
            (t2.date BETWEEN @start2 AND @end2)
        GROUP BY t2.userID
    ) AS G2 ON G1.userID = G2.userID
WHERE 
    G1.percentage1 < G2.percentage2
```

But if you want to use only one select from the table then you can also try this.

```
DECLARE @start DATE
DECLARE @end DATE

SET @start = CASE WHEN @start1 < @start2 THEN @start1 ELSE @start2 END
SET @end = CASE WHEN @end1 > @end2 THEN @end1 ELSE @end2 END

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.userID, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN @start1 AND @end1 THEN t.value1 END ) / SUM( CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN @start1 AND @end1 THEN t.value2 END ) AS percentage1, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN @start2 AND @end2 THEN t.value1 END ) / SUM( CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN @start2 AND @end2 THEN t.value2 END ) AS percentage2, 
    FROM table AS t
    WHERE 
        (t.date BETWEEN @start AND @end)
    GROUP BY t.userID
) AS SQ WHERE percentage1 < percentage2
```

Comment: This is two select statements and that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I added one select version.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using CTE approach, provides more readability and flexible for modifications if required in future. I have added indexes to RequiredDate Column to improve performance. Hope it helps.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InputUsers') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE dbo.InputUsers (
UserNameID INT NOT NULL,
UserName NVARCHAR(MAX),
RequiredDate DATETIME,
Value1 DECIMAL,
Value2 DECIMAL
)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Users_RequiredDate   
    ON dbo.InputUsers (RequiredDate);   
END

DECLARE @Start1 NVARCHAR(20), @End1 NVARCHAR(20), @Start2 NVARCHAR(20), @End2 NVARCHAR(20)
SET @Start1 = '2018-05-26'
SET @End1 = '2018-05-27'

SET @Start2 = '2018-05-28'
SET @End2 = '2018-05-29'

INSERT INTO InputUsers(UserNameID, UserName, RequiredDate, Value1, Value2) VALUES
(1, 'Adam', '2018-05-29', 13, 25),
(1, 'Adam', '2018-05-28', 12, 25),
(1, 'Adam', '2018-05-27', 11, 25),
(1, 'Adam', '2018-05-26', 10, 25),

(2, 'Lisa', '2018-05-29', 19, 25),
(2, 'Lisa', '2018-05-28', 18, 25),
(2, 'Lisa', '2018-05-27', 17, 25),
(2, 'Lisa', '2018-05-26', 16, 25),

(3, 'John', '2018-05-29', 16, 25),
(3, 'John', '2018-05-28', 17, 25),
(3, 'John', '2018-05-27', 18, 25),
(3, 'John', '2018-05-26', 19, 25),

(4, 'Bill', '2018-05-29', 10, 25),
(4, 'Bill', '2018-05-28', 11, 25),
(4, 'Bill', '2018-05-27', 12, 25),
(4, 'Bill', '2018-05-26', 13, 25)

;WITH PercentageValues1 AS (SELECT UserNameID, UserName, SUM(Value1)*100 / SUM(Value2) AS Percentage
FROM dbo.InputUsers
WHERE RequiredDate >= @Start1 AND RequiredDate <= @End1
GROUP BY UserNameID, UserName
),
PercentageValues2 AS (SELECT UserNameID, UserName, SUM(Value1)*100 / SUM(Value2) AS Percentage
FROM dbo.InputUsers
WHERE RequiredDate >= @Start2 AND RequiredDate <= @End2
GROUP BY UserNameID, UserName
)
SELECT pv2.UserName, pv1.Percentage, pv2.Percentage
FROM PercentageValues2 pv2
LEFT JOIN PercentageValues1 pv1 ON 
pv2.UserNameID = pv1.UserNameID
WHERE pv2.Percentage > pv1.Percentage
```

Comment: It might get challenging to solve this by using single select statements. Maybe try out the above code and let me know about performance.